# ¿Como puedo asignar un evento a un control creado? Visual basic

Tags: visual-studio, vb.net, vb

Tengo un problema con el tema de los eventos, estoy realizando un formulario en el que se muestran los productos mediante botones creados con codigo, dando el resultado de la imagen[image: prendas cargadas por mysql]

pero no se como darle una accion propia a cada boton, trate de usar el AddHandler con AddressOf pero hace que todos los productos tengan los valores del ultimo leido (Id del producto).

```
Public Sub load_buttons_dress(contender As FlowLayoutPanel)
    Using connection = Getconnection()
        connection.Open()
        Using command = New MySqlCommand()
            command.Connection = connection
            command.CommandText = "sp_view_productos"
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Dim reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Id1 = Convert.ToInt32(reader(0))
                Marca1 = Convert.ToString(reader(1))
                Talla1 = Convert.ToString(reader(2))
                Color1 = Convert.ToString(reader(3))
                Genero1 = Convert.ToString(reader(4))
                Modelo1 = Convert.ToString(reader(5))
                Des1 = Convert.ToString(reader(6))
                Price1 = Convert.ToDecimal(reader(7))
                Img1 = reader(8)
                Dim btn As New Ropabtn()
                btn.ID = Id1
                btn.Marca = Marca1
                btn.Talla = Talla1
                btn.Color = Color1
                btn.Genero = Genero1
                btn.Modelo = Modelo1
                btn.Descripcion = Des1
                btn.Precio = "S/." + Price1.ToString()
                Dim ms As New MemoryStream(Img1)
                btn.ImagenProducto = Image.FromStream(ms)
                contender.Controls.Add(btn)
                AddHandler btn.Click_buy, AddressOf open_form
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub

Public Sub open_form(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim frm As New Form
    frm.Enabled = True
    frm.Visible = True
    frm.Size = New Size(500, 500)
    frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow
    frm.Show()
    Dim btn2 As New Button
    btn2.Text = Id1
    btn2.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
    btn2.Enabled = True
    btn2.Visible = True
    frm.Controls.Add(btn2)
End Sub
```

La idea es que cada producto abra una ventana con su propio id, no se mucho del manejo de eventos

Comment: Intenta algo como `AddHandler btn.Click_buy, Function(sender, e) open_form(Id1)` Para ello igual tienes que modificar tu metodo open_form para que reciba el id

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias me sirvio la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Intenta agregar un evento Click al botón al que le has de dar un nombre...

```
Public Sub open_form(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   Dim frm As New Form
   frm.Enabled = True
   frm.Visible = True
   frm.Size = New Size(500, 500)
   frm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.SizableToolWindow
   frm.Show()
   Dim btn2 As New Button
   btn2.Name = "btn2"
   btn2.Text = Id1
   btn2.ForeColor = SystemColors.ControlText
   btn2.Enabled = True
   btn2.Visible = True
frm.Controls.Add(btn2)
End Sub

Private Sub Button_Click(ByVal Sender As System.Object, 
                         ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn2.Click
   Dim frm As New Form
   frm.Show()
End Sub
```